# How to specify PluginFamily for generic types? Options

Tags: structuremap

Please I have 2 questions: 
1. How to specify PluginFamily for this scenario:

```
For<IRepository<Person>>(). Use<Repository<Person>>() 
For<IRepository<Address>>().Use<Repository<Address>>()
```

1. How to specify pluginfamily attribute for this scenarion:

   For(typeof(IRepository<>)).User(typeof(Repository<>));

Please help 
thanks

Comment: The registrations you show are valid. What more are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't want to use registries. I want to use attributes. So I want to decorate my interface with attributes [PluginFamily...] and [Pluggable]

Comment: If you have 2 question, you should really create 2 separate questions on the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can achieve the first one with attributes, but the second one is just this:

```
[PluginFamily]
public interface IRepository<T> {}

[Pluggable("Default")]
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
```